# Is it safe (from portability perspective) to use ElementRef

Tags: angular

I have read that using `ElementRef` directly to manipulate the `DOM` is not advisable. However, most of the examples I have seen online seem to use `ElementRef` directly. Is it wrong to use `ElementRef`?

Eg

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `
        <span #tref>I am span</span>
    `
})
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("tref", {read: ElementRef}) tref: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // outputs `I am span`
        console.log(this.tref.nativeElement.textContent);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `
        <span >I am span</span>


export class SampleComponent{
    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {
        //outputs <sample>...</sample>
        console.log(this.hostElement.nativeElement.outerHTML);
    }
```

**Question1**

Are the above examples portable? If now, what should I do to make them portable?

**Question2**
I checked `ElementRef`'s class. It has only one member `nativeElement` which is probably another abstraction. Where could I find more information about methods available in `nativeElement`? Is it safe to use those methods?

Comment: `nativeElement` is DOM element, and the methods are same as they would be on one. Of course, it's not safe, and that's the reason why abstractions were introduced. Some things may not work on server side, although outerHTML and textContent likely will. `nativeElement` is not necessarily DOM, it can be native UI in NativeScript. The question is potential XY problem, since it's unclear why there's a need to get contents of static template element.

Comment: If possible, prefer to use Renderer2 (or new Ivy renderer if available as of Angular 6)

Comment: I just checked `Renderer2`. I notice some of its apis (eg `setClass`) need `ElementRef`. Do you mean that I could use abstractions like Renderer2 and `ElementRef` but should avoid methods like `nativeElement`. Instead I should rely on `Renderer2` 's APIs to modify the element referenced by `ElementRef`?

Comment: David - I'll happily do so but I am still doing my experiments to evaluate the answers. From what I have learned so far, it seems I'll have to use `el.nativeElement`. My doubt still is whether it is a safe way to keep the code portable. Give me some more time so that I could develop better understanding of the concepts

Answer (score 0):

`nativeElement` is simply the DOM object, as you would get is by a `document.getElementById()` with the basic javascript API (you can look on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API) for learning the internal javascript API).

The principle in Angular is to use angular unless you can't.
If you reach the limit of the framework you should use `ElementRef` to work on the element.

For exemple recently I create a parallax effect when I scroll using DOM element.

For basic CRUD/Ajax operation you should only use Angular